# On namespaces, classes and scope

Tags: c++

I have a class `NormalCalculator`. Within `NormalCalculator`, I have defined a `struct` `GLpoint`.

As my project has progressed, I have found uses for `GLpoint` elsewhere in my code, but I find it untidy and screen-polluting to have to write `NormalCalculator::GLpoint` every time I wish to use the `GLpoint struct` elsewhere in my solution, outside of the `NormalCalculator` class.

Is there any way I can let the compiler know that `GLpoint` exists in `NormalCalculator.h`, and for it to just let me refer to it as `GLpoint`? I'm pretty sure there should be a way.

I've tried

```
using NormalCalculator
```

and

```
using NormalCalculator::GLpoint
```

as expected, these didn't work as `NormalCalculator` is a class and not a namespace.

Comment: If you need it in a namespace, then why not declare it in the namespace rather than a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef NormalCalculator::GLpoint GLpoint;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a typedef.

```
namespace my_ns {
typedef NormalCalculator::GLpoint GLpoint;
}
```

Although I really recommend to simply refactor the code base. Most
error messages emitted by the compiler will still use the complete
typename qualified with scope and long type names become a real
readability problem.

Consider this code which I often use to print typenames to debug
templates:

```
struct Foo
{
  struct Bar {};
};

typedef Foo::Bar ImportedBar;

// refactored bar
struct Bar {};

template <typename> struct print;

int main()
{
  print<ImportedBar> x; // error: aggregate ‘print<Foo::Bar> x’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
  print<Bar> y; // error: aggregate ‘print<Bar> y’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
  return 0;
}
```

The first version still prints the full name. This might look like a
small deal to you, but consider what happens if this is a
`std::vector` with template default arguments and all that. Suddenly
every character helps to read this.

Comment: When you say refactor the code base, do you mean organise my code so that GLpoint is in a more convenient place making it more easily visible to my other classes? 
Anyway this typedef method is working for me, so thanks.

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean No, I mean to actually move GLpoint into the scope. I added an example to illustrate what I mean.